# Passing multiple test data to ginkgo test.go file

Tags: go, ginkgo

I have a test method like below:

```
It("test description", func() { 
    expectcc.ResponseOk(name.Invoke(`issue`, &cpaper.test{
        Issuer:       IssuerName,
        PaperNumber:  "0001",
        IssueDate:    time.Now(),
        MaturityDate: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 30 * 6),
        FaceValue:    100000,
    }
```

How I can test the function with different test data?

Comment: This probably is what you looking for https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#table-driven-tests

Comment: Whether we have any solution to get input from user or any file formats??

Comment: Generally there is no user input in a unit test. I can provide an example for file but would need more info. What does the file look like (e.g. is it a CSV)?

Comment: Ya. Input with any file formats is comfortable. Can you please share the example.

Comment: Can you provide the file example